# Why are the six prongs of a snowflake the same?

Tags: symmetry, water, crystals, ice

My understanding is that the variety in snowflakes is determined by pressure, temperature, and humidity. This is why the six prongs grow same way, because they are close enough that they are in the same conditions. If this is correct then a corollary is that we can create identical snowflakes in controlled laboratory conditions. The only alternative I see to this theory is if the first few steps in the growth of the snowflake somehow encode the rest of the shape.

Comment: It seems like you answered your own question. Did you have some unspecified question remaining?

Comment: My question is if this is right. I hope the explanation I gave is correct, I'm just looking for confirmation or correction.